# Bug in Migrating md5 to hash in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hash, md5

The algorithm works, but once the password has been converted to hash and saved into the database, it doesn't redirect to the homepage. Instead, it redirects to the login page saying that the login credentials is incorrect. But if I tried logging in, it is ok. What am I doing wrong?

AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $check = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );
    if ($check === false)
    {
        $user = User::where('username','=',$request->input('username'))->first();

        if(isset($user)) {
            if($user->password == md5($request->input('password'))) { // If their password is still MD5
                $hashed_password = Hash::make($request['password']); // Convert to new format
                $user->password = $hashed_password;
                $user->save();

                return $this->guard()->attempt(
                    array(
                        'username'=>$request->input('username'),
                        'password'=>$hashed_password
                    ), $request->has('remember')
                );

            } else {
                // Redirect to the login page.
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return $check;
}
```

Comment: So you imagine that the user could login using `md5 hashed password`?

Comment: yup, coz i am replacing the current md5 into laravel's hash. But the issue is after that.

Comment: So you need to convert the existent md5 password in your database into `laravel hashing`? if so try to say `if (password_verify($request->input('password'), $user->password))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attempt` doesn't take the hashed password, it takes the password you would get from the user (the plain text password). The user doesn't know the hashed version of their password and `attempt` does a hash check which requires the plain text version.

You also don't need to call `attempt` that second time if you have already validated the user and their credentials and have a User instance that represents them. Just use `login` to log them in at that point. You don't have to go through `attempt` which is just going to requery the database to get the user, then check the hash that you know is correct since you just set it.

To a degree part of the code you have is just recreating what `attempt` does internally.

Also you don't need to query the database yourself for the User. That first call to `attempt` will have held onto the 'user' it found from when it queried the database. You can retrieve it from the guard so you don't have to query the database again, `$this->guard()->getLastAttempted()`.

Making these changes will remove the 'bad credentials' issue coming from the second `attempt` call, since it won't be called any more. This will also cut your queries down from 3 selects and 1 update to 1 select and 1 update. (roughly)

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation man, here's what I did after saving it to the database.
    `$request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    Auth::login($user, true);`